# Identifying the contrapositive of this statement $x>0$, then $∃_{y>0}$ such that $x>y$

Tags: logic

Statement: If $x>0$, then $∃_{y>0}$ such that $x>y$. (x and y are real numbers)

Contrapositive: If $∀_{y>0}$ $x<y$, then $x≤0$.

Is the contrapositive correct?

Comment: Your proposed contrapositive is correct, but using a mixture of natural language and logical notation makes things much more difficult than sticking to logical notation.

Comment: "If $x>0$", in this context, should read $\forall x>0$.

Comment: Indeed, Rob Arthan.  As I tried to argue in my comment above, if $x>0$ applies to *all (x> 0).

Comment: PS: to amplify my point about mixing natural language and logical notation making things difficult, $x < y$ in the contrapositive statement in the question should actually read $x \le y$ (but the resulting statement is equivalent).

Comment: You cannot choose $ x=y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first statement should be

Let $ x\in \Bbb R$.

$$x>0\implies (\exists y>0 : x>y)$$

The contrapositive is

$$(\forall y>0\;\; x\le y) \implies x\le 0$$

Answer (score 0):

The negation of $x\gt y$ is $x\le y$, not $x\lt y$, so the correct contrapositive is "If $\forall_{y\gt0}x\le y$ then $x\le 0$," not "If $\forall_{y\gt0}x\lt y$ then $x\le 0$." Your concern with choosing $x=y$ is illogical; $y$ here is a bound variable (bound by the $\forall$ quantifier), so it makes no sense to "choose" to set it equal to the (free) variable $x$.